# For a group G, find all x such that $x^2=x$

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group. 
Find all solutions x in G to the equation x^2 = x.

I do not understand where I need to start in solving the problem.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$.

Comment: If $x \in G$, then $x^{-1}$ exists. Multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$.

Comment: You're going to want to multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{array}
\ x^2=x &\implies x^2 x^{-1} = xx^{-1} \\
&\implies x(xx^{-1})=e \\
&\implies xe=e \\
&\implies x = e
\end{array}

We used the fact that since $G$ is a group then $\forall x \in G$ there exists an element $x^{-1}\in G$ such that $xx^{-1}=e$, the property concerning identies, and that $G$ is associative. So all the properties!

Comment: So, the question is essentially asking you to solve for x and using what we know about groups, like it being associative and and that it has an inverse, we use these facts to solve for x. Thank you for your help

Comment: @NAT Essentially! You were asked to find elements $x$ of the group that satisfy the expression, but by simply manipulating the expression (through the group axioms) the solutuon became more clear -- entirely clear actually.

Comment: @NAT yes, you have just realized now what abstract algebra is all about.

Comment: Note the same arguments lead to the *cancellation rule* in groups.

Comment: @NAT Actually, technically speaking, we even used the identity property of groups inbetween $x(xx^{-1})$ and $x$! I've added that in. All three properties were used!