# Groups Abstract Algebra

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Find all solutions $x$ in $G$ to the equation $x^2 = x^3$.

This is what I have tried so far:

$x^2 = x^3 \Rightarrow x^2 = x^2 x$

$\Rightarrow x^2 x^{-1} = x^x x x^{-1}$

$\Rightarrow x(xx^{-1}) = x^2 (xx^{-1})$

$\Rightarrow x e = x^2 e$

$\Rightarrow x= x^2$

Is it just going to come out to be $e$?

Comment: Yup. Bingo. ${}{}$

Comment: It has been asked a similar question some minutes ago (probably by a colleague of yours): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2424533/309917

Comment: @NAT You might find this one interesting.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct.  You can get this a little more efficiently by multiplying both sides of the given equation by $x^{-2}$.

Comment: So, my final answer is going to be $x = e$ and i get this by multiplying both sides by the inverse again.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.